# Camera in landscape mode

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation, landscape-portrait

I'm using AVFoundation framework to manage the camera. When I'm in landscape mode, I would like to keep my shoot button on the right side of the screen like this picture :

[image]

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: As per the [documentation],The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only
    However, you can use cameraViewTransform to scale your UIImagePickerController and a custom cameraOverlayView.          the default controls are to be put off `yourCameraPickerCtrl.showsCameraControls=NO;`
 I used CGAffineTransformScale on cameraViewTransform to get rid of black spaces. Corresponding delegate and button actions (of your custom cameraOverlayView) should be implemented.

Comment: I'm not using UIImagePickerController but a custom class that mimics the UIImagePickerController using AVFoundation framework. In fact, the shoot button is a simple UIButton that I added on top of my UIViewController that manages my custom camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my solution.

1) disable autorotation, (I assume you don't want to rotate entire view)

2) register your view controller as an observer for UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceOrientationDidChange) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    ...
}
```

and also be sure to invoke removeObserver before your observer object is deallocated.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}
```

3) handle orientation changes

```
- (void)deviceOrientationDidChange {
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    switch (orientation) {
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
        {
            [self rotateInterfaceWithDegrees:0.0];
        }
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        {
            [self rotateInterfaceWithDegrees:180.0];
        }
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        {
            [self rotateInterfaceWithDegrees:90.0];
        }
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        {
            [self rotateInterfaceWithDegrees:270.0];
        }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

4) make rotation transform and apply on your buttons

```
- (void)rotateInterfaceWithDegrees:(NSUInteger)degrees {
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degrees*M_PI/180.0);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3   // with animation
                     animations:^{    // optional
                         yourFirstButton.transform = transform;
                         yourSecondButton.transform = transform;
                         ...
                     }];
}
```

Hope it helps.